# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable while running multi processing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn multiprocessing in python. I wrote 2 simple function and wanted to run both in parallel. I am getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Here is the code I have:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def add(a):
    t=0
    for i in range(a):
        t=i+1
    return t
def subtract (b):
    q=0
    for j in range(b):
        q=j+1
    return (q)

a=100000000
b=100000000

p1 = Process(target=add(a))
p1.start()
print("r")
p2 = Process(target=subtract(b))
p2.start()
print("q")

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

This is the error log I get:

> Process Process-24: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
>   line 297, in _bootstrap
>       self.run()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
>   line 99, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) r Process Process-25: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
>   line 297, in _bootstrap
>       self.run()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
>   line 99, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `target` argument to [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) needs to be a function not a function call. Try:

```
Process(target=add, args=(a,))
```

Instead.

From the docs:

> *target* is the callable object to be invoked by the `run()` method. It defaults to `None`, meaning nothing is called. ... *args* is the argument tuple for the target invocation.

In your invocation (`p1 = Process(target=add(a))`) you are passing the *result* of the `add()` function as the `target` callback, instead of the `add()` function itself.

Comment: Thank you so much.